# Coloring a second layer of a ggplot2 scatterplot by a separate color scheme without adding to data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, scatter-plot

I'm trying to develop a Shiny applet that's essentially a scatterplot in grey, with several highlighted points plotted on top in another color. What I need is for the points plotted on top of the grey points to follow a specific color scheme, determined by another variable. As far as I can tell, this would be relatively simple to do by merging those values into the data frame, but since this is a shiny app, this comes with a big time cost (some of these datasets have tens of thousands of points), since the original data frame would need to be recalculated every time that subset of points is changed (instead of just the plot itself being updated with a different subset plotted).

Somehow, I can't get the second layer of data to follow the desired color scheme (see below, I've also tried other scale_*_ functions with non-user-defined color schemes, and it won't budge either). I've tried varying the location of the call as well.

Here is my code, devoid of the shiny context (and with generic data, variable examples for simplification):

```
library(ggplot2)
#color scheme I want the highlighted points to be in
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000", "red", "#FF7F00", "yellow", "#7FFF7F", "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue", "#00007F"))

#points to plot
test.data <- data.frame(variabs = runif(144*96),means = runif(144*96))

#variable to color highlighted points by (put in a grid the same size as the input data)
lat <- seq(-90,90,by=180/95) #(it's geospatial data)
latyy <- t(matrix(1,96,144)*abs(lat))

#which points to highlight/plot again in color
idx_region <- sample(seq(1:(96*144)),250)

#ggplot setup 
p <-  ggplot(test.data,
          aes_string(x="means",y="variabs")) +
      geom_point(size=0.5,color="grey",show.legend=FALSE) + ## First (gray) points layer
      geom_point(data=test.data[idx_region,], ## Second (highlighted, colored) points layer
                 aes_string(x="means",y="variabs"),
                 color=latyy[idx_region],
                 size=1,show.legend=TRUE) +
      scale_colour_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(18)) + ## My attempt at coloring
      labs(x = "Mean",y = "Variability") + 
      geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1,linetype='dashed') +
      geom_hline(yintercept=0) + geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What, exactly, is the desired effect?

Comment: So the desired effect is more or less the outputted scatterplot - except with a way to set the color scheme that maps the values of latyy to the color of the 'highlighted' points (so basically a way to change the color mapping of the non-grey points). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `color=latyy[idx_region]` within the `aes_string` to specify color comes from data (as opposed to `color="grey" which is defined outside aes_string):

```
ggplot(test.data,
             aes_string(x="means",y="variabs")) +
  geom_point(size=0.5,color="grey",show.legend=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data=test.data[idx_region,], 
             aes_string(x="means",y="variabs",
             color="latyy[idx_region]"),
             size=1,show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(18)) +
  labs(x = "Mean",y = "Variability") + 
  geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1,linetype='dashed') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) + geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```